# How to link cloudbuild.yaml from different repository (Google Cloud Build trigger)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Basically I want to link my `cloudbuild.yaml` from within my testing environment to my dev environment.

I have a trigger every time I commit on my testing env, my tests run and generate a report (per the yaml). Great.

But I want to create a trigger when my dev environment commits, my tests run from my testing repository and create the reports.

Comment: If I understand well, when you commit in your dev environment, you want to clone your testing project and performs tests with it, isn't it?

Comment: yes Guillaume my helpful friend

Comment: Based on what cloud build triggers are available, there is not one where when you modify a file(s) in a certain project, the changes will cause a build in another project. You need to manually trigger the second project’s Cloud Build which you can find here [1].

https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/running-builds/create-manage-triggers#build_trigger [1]

Comment: I know about the triggers, I read all the documentation but I'm still not able to create a right trigger. This is the case: I have 2 projects: dev and test. If the dev projects commits and builds, I need my test project to build automatically as well (because the yaml in the test project builds and runs the tests). 

What trigger should I put in what project for this purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 solutions for doing this.

First, you can download your test project and run a Cloud Build from the current execution of the dev build

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/git
  args: ['clone', 'https://myrepo.com/testing']
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
  args: ["builds", "submit"]
  dir: "testing"   # I assume that the git clone has created the testing directory
```

The advantage of this solution is if your Cloud Build on Test project failed, you know it synchronously and you can react on this on your Dev current build

The counterpart is that the processing time is duplicated during the test build. Indeed, the test build is performed, and the dev test continue (even in standby) to wait the test build end. You also need to set correctly the Cloud Build timeout.

---

Second solution is an API call to trigger manually your test Cloud Build trigger.

For this you need to customize the step bellow with:

- The test project ID
- The trigger UUID. You can find it in the page URL when you click on your trigger for editing it.

[image]

You can also change the `branchName` if you want

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
             curl -d '{"branchName":"master"}' -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud config config-helper --format='value(credential.access_token)')" https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<PROJECT_TEST_ID>/triggers/<TRIGGER_UUID>:run
```

Here, you don't wait the end of the build and you save Cloud Build duration (and money), but you can't react in case of build failed.

Comment: You helped me a great deal earlier, but you lost me here. I don't use Cloud Service and in my cloudbuild.yaml I refer to the gsutil cloud-builder.

I am not sure what you mean, why would I clone the build? I need my test project build to run whenever my dev build is ran (these are 2 different projects in my GAE)

Comment: I'm sorry, I simply don't understand correctly your need. And I'm still not sure to well understand: What do you mean by "I need my test project build to run whenever my dev build is ran"? Do you need the source code of `test project`? Another thing is not clear "these are 2 different projects in my GAE" -> Do you mean "these are 2 different `services` in my GAE"?

Comment: Yeah I am sorry im new to this. I need my `cloudbuild.yaml`, which is located in my test project, to run whenever a new commit and push (build) is done on the dev project. Because I have my automation tests in my test project and I store the results in my storage with my `cloudbuild.yaml`, I need this to run everytime the code is changed in the dev project. To check if all tests still pass you see? 

I just have my Google Cloud Platform setup with two projects, a dev and a test project. I dont know what you mean with `services`.

Comment: Ok, to summarize: when you build the `dev` projet, you want to replay the `test` project build ? if so, your question is: How can you re-run the `test` build when a `dev` build is running?

Comment: Great. I updated my answer, I hope that I correctly caught your need now!

Comment: I'm looking at your edit, are these steps to be configured in the DEV or TST code? And it;s an extra step in the cloudbuild.yaml rite?

Comment: which trigger should I use as well, I have the DEV and the TST trigger configured

Comment: During your Dev build you want to trigger the TEST trigger. Thus, add this step in the DEV yaml to trigger the TEST. -> You need the test trigger UUID

Comment: Add the TEST trigger step where you want, I thing it's better at the end of the DEV build, but all depends on your needs

Comment: I got next error: `"error": {
"code": 403,
 "message": "The caller does not have permission",
 "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
`

Comment: Okay I had to change the branchname to the right branche and it looks like its working! thanks so much. Where did you get this info? How did you know what to do, what to look for and where? Thanks man

Comment: ..... It's the part that I forget in my answer. I would like to speak about the security/role and I forgot. Is the 2 trigger are in the same project or is it 2 separated project?

Comment: More detail [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.triggers/run)